# What is the easy way of installing chrome app from folder, for development, after loading will be disallowed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Google Chrome will start disallowing developers from installing Chrome apps by loading them from a folder as it's possible today (see [the recent news from chromium team](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/05/continuing-to-protect-chrome-users-from.html)).

However, the [proposed solution](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453) seems really complicated to me and I don't understand it at all (for example, I don't have any CRX file in the first place, I just have some javascript files and manifest in a folder).

So, I want to ask. I am developing an extension that I have in a folder. How to easily load the extension in Chrome after the protections will start being enforced everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I misunderstood the news. Installing through "Load unpacked extension" will still be possible, as explained here

https://www.chromium.org/developers/extensions-deployment-faq#TOC-Will-this-affect-my-ability-to-develop-my-extensions-on-Windows-